# How to disable 'Exit Full Screen' with escape on Yosemite

Tags: macos, fullscreen

If I press <kbd>Escape</kbd> by mistake while working, it exits full screen mode.

I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> if I want to exit full screen mode. How can I prevent <kbd>Escape</kbd> key in full screen mode?

Comment: You can set this in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. Look for the escape key, replace it with something else. Add a keyboard shortcut (If there isn't an existing one) And set Ctrl+Cmd+F to exit fullscreen. You can make an automator service to exit fullscreen if there isn't a function on it already (I am not on my mac now, so I cannot be 100% sure)

Comment: Thanks The Bro21, I could see the 'Launchpad & Dock', 'Mission Control', 'Keyboard', 'Input Sources' 'Screen Shots', 'Services', 'Spotlight', 'Accessibility', 'App Shortcuts', but I couldn't see any assignment to 'ESC' key now. sad..
But I appreciate your contribution.

Comment: I think you double click the service, then press ESC to assign

Comment: As far as I can tell, the service is not available to change the shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, you could go ahead and brute-force disable the Escape key in
>   Safari. But that'd defeat the purpose of still allowing Escape to work
>   as a shortcut in the aforementioned places, which I'd rather avoid.

[image]

http://patricklenz.co/blog/2014/9/1/dont-escape-full-screen-mode-in-safari

Btw I think that your question is a duplicate : [Disable Escape key in Safari for getting out of full screen mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110371/disable-escape-key-in-safari-for-getting-out-of-full-screen-mode/207953#207953)